# POSTGRES UPDATE ON CONFLICT. Error cannot affect a row a second time (dupes) ONLY OCCURS IN FUNCTION. Not as query

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have a query in a function that does not seem to be returning any duplicates from my checks and if ran as a separate query... it works! If ran within a stored function, it gives the error ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time.

This makes no sense.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rollups.compute_daily_rollups_every_hour(
start_time timestamp without time zone,
end_time timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'Computing daily rollups from % to % (excluded)', start_time, end_time;

RAISE NOTICE 'Aggregating data into daily_rollup';
EXECUTE $$
    INSERT INTO rollups.daily_rollup
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(visitors, 0) AS visitors, COALESCE(total_dwell_time, 0) AS total_dwell_time, d.datestamp::date,  doorway_id, customer_id, centre_id, postcode, gender, age_group, house_income, no_children, no_cars, shopping_frequency, marital_status, employment_status
        FROM (
            Select date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)) AS datestamp
            FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
        ) AS D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT cv.datestamp,
                round((date_part('epoch'::text, sum(cv.dwell_time)) / 60::double precision)::numeric, 2) AS total_dwell_time,
                count(cv.sensor_id) AS visitors,
                cv.doorway_id,
                cv.customer_id,
                cv.centre_id,
                cv.gender,
                cv.postcode,
                cv.age_group,
                cv.no_children,
                cv.no_cars,
                cv.marital_status,
                cv.employment_status,
                cv.shopping_frequency,
                cv.house_income
            FROM rollups.some_rollup cv
            WHERE cv.dwell_time > '00:00:30'::interval
            GROUP BY cv.datestamp, cv.doorway_id, cv.customer_id, cv.centre_id, cv.gender, cv.postcode, cv.age_group, cv.no_children, cv.no_cars, cv.marital_status, cv.employment_status, cv.shopping_frequency, cv.house_income
                ) AS t1
            ON d.datestamp::date = t1.datestamp::date
            WHERE d.datestamp >= $1 AND d.datestamp < $2
            ORDER BY d.datestamp
    ON CONFLICT (datestamp, doorway_id, customer_id, centre_id, gender, postcode, age_group, no_children, no_cars, marital_status, employment_status, shopping_frequency, house_income)
    DO UPDATE SET visitors=excluded.visitors, total_dwell_time = excluded.total_dwell_time;$$
USING start_time, end_time;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Sorry I felt that there were many questions about duplicate records, I cant find anything on issues with functions and I didnt want it read as just more dupes in the result set :( (also the first part was just copied raw sql lol)

Comment: This depends on the data in the table. Try to create a self-contained reproducible test case.

Comment: I knew someone would ask that. That will take me some time, but I will add it to this question when I get the chance. The above query is just a snippet from about 7 queries lumped in one function, its the only query of the 7 that acts in this way, it also gets its data from a table that was produced within the same function. I havent seen any reason for that to have an affect though.

For now I will be removing them from the function and running them as single queries in a python file.